# Nested content inside component template

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I have a component called 'select-other', and inside i have two elements that i need to get the contents of and print inside my 'select-other' component template.

**HTML**

```
<select-other>
  <options>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
  </options>

  <other>
    <input>
    <button></button>
  </other>
</select-other>
```

**Component Decorator**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-other',
  template: `
    <select
      *ngIf="select !== 'other'"
      [(ngModel)]="select"
      class="form-control"
    >
      // CONTENT FROM INSIDE <OPTIONS> HERE
      <option
        value="other"
      >Other</option>
    </select>
    // CONTENT FROM INSIDE <OTHER> HERE
  `
})
```

I understand i can use 'ng-content' inside the template to print what's between my 'select-other' tags, but i'm a tad confused how i'd go about getting the content from different elements within and printing them where i want in the template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `ng-content` content projection like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'select-other',
    template: `
       <select
       *ngIf="select !== 'other'"
       [(ngModel)]="select"
       class="form-control">
           // CONTENT FROM INSIDE <OPTIONS> HERE
           <ng-content select="options"></ng-content>

           <option value="other">Other</option>
       </select>
       // CONTENT FROM INSIDE <OTHER> HERE
       <ng-content select="other"></ng-content>
    `
})
```

So you can select needed content by its parent element selector.
More about this [here](https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content)